# freeing container does it free the child both allocated on heap. I do not think that

Tags: c

I have two structs

```
struct request
{
    char *request;
    char *rand;
    int status;

}
struct container 
{
    int new_socket;
    struct request **request;
}
```

let say I create a pointer of request

```
 struct request *requests = malloc(sizeof(struct request));
```

and I create pointer pointing to space in heap of container like

```
 struct container *con=malloc(sizeof(struct container))
```

and I do

```
 con->new_socket = 1;
 con->request= &request
```

and if I free like free(con), And so I really don't thing my requests pointer get freed. I think its present and I can access elements of it like `*(requests+0)->status` and this will be ok. Is this correct understanding if I am `struct request requests` accessible somewhere else in my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And so I really don't thing my requests pointer get freed.

That's correct. free() only frees a single malloc(). If you call malloc() twice, and free() once, then only one of the two allocations is freed.

If you run this code:

```c
struct request *requests = malloc(sizeof(struct request));
struct container *con=malloc(sizeof(struct container))
con->new_socket = 1;
con->request= &request;
free(con);
```

then the heap memory pointed to by the `requests` pointer will not be freed.

Comment: what if after freeing I also do assign null to con then what my requests will be NULL or all good and can be accessible

Comment: @user786 All good. Setting con to NULL doesn't affect the value of requests, or whether requests is freed.